# AccessDenied when deploying serverless via aws-vault

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to deploy serverless with the credentials stored in my [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault) keychain.

However when I run `aws-vault exec myprofile -- sls deploy` I receive the following error:

`An error occurred: MyLambdaFunction - AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call iam:GetRole.`

The user has AdministratorAccess and I also gave him IAMFullAccess (which should not be needed)

When I deploy with the same credentials stored in `~.aws/credentials` with `sls deploy`
it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html) the session token generated by `aws-vault` has some restrictions:

- You cannot call any IAM API operations unless MFA authentication information is included in the request.
- You cannot call any AWS STS API except AssumeRole or GetCallerIdentity.

A work around is to use the [--no-session](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault/blob/master/USAGE.md#using---no-session)

so `aws-vault exec myprofile --no-session -- sls deploy` works without any error.